# field usr not available with web service rest

Tags: acumatica

I would like to modify a usrfield with a web service while the document is integrated

[image]

In the app I made the field editable

```
    protected void POReceipt_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (POReceipt)e.Row;
  if (row != null)
  {
    Base.Document.Cache.AllowUpdate=true;
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<POReceiptExt.usrtransfertedi>(cache,row,true);
  }
}
```

however the webservice does not take this notion

```
   {"ReceiptNbr":{"value":"000398"},"TransfertEDI":{"value":"ENV"}}
```

It works when the status is on hold & Balanced but not release

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the custom field in the API, you will need to enhance the Default web service endpoint. This can be done by using the Web Services Endpoint Screen. Here choose the endpoint you are using and press extend endpoint. Then locate the Purchase Receipt endpoint and add the custom field under the fields section.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but the endpoint is already extended, updating the field works, but not when the document has the releases status

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to assume this might be an acumatica bug as you have code in place that is allowing you to manually correct this. You should in theory have no issue with this. I would suggest opening a ticket with Acumatica to see what they have to say.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'm waiting for the ACUMATICA editor, have you ever done this type of action on closed recordings ?